# How to know which implementation will going to use while returning interface refrance

Tags: java, class, interface, return

```
@Override
public IEntity updateEntity(IEntity entity) {
    String entityType = null;
    try {
        entityType = getEntityType(entity);
        if (entity != null) {

            getHibernateTemplate().merge(entity);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ExceptionUtils.throwVSXException(entityType, e);
    }
    return entity;
}
```

public interface IEntity extends Serializable {

```
ConnectivityEntity getConnectivityEntity();}
```

while IEntity is a interface and implemented so many classes how to understand which implemented class will use this returning value

Answer (score 1):

You can use `instanceof` operator and check the implementing class. For example if class A and B implement `IEntity` interface than you can check like:

```
@Override
public IEntity updateEntity(IEntity entity) {
   String entityType = ""; // Returing null is bad
   ...... 

   if(entity instanceof A){
    entityType="A class"
   }
   else if(entity instanceof B){
    entityType= "B class"
   }
   return entityType
 }
```